# View with sums returning partial or incorrect data set

Tags: mysql

I have the following view. I need to see the sums as indicated for each PartNum for each date. But the view returns an incorrect data set only showing certain dates. Can someone set me straight?

```
SELECT
    `archived_items`.`ArcPartNumber` AS `PartNum`,
    `archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate` AS `DeliveryDate`,
    `archived_items`.`ArcTransactionNumber` AS `TransactionNumber`,
    sum(`archived_items`.`ArcOrdered`) AS `Ordered`,
    sum(`archived_items`.`ArcShipped`) AS `Shipped`,
    sum(`archived_items`.`ArcBackOrdered`) AS `BackOrdered`
FROM
    ( `archived_items`
        LEFT JOIN `archived_header` ON (
            (`archived_header`.`AhTransactionNumber` = `archived_items`.`ArcTransactionNumber`
        )))
WHERE
((`archived_items`.`ArcTransactionType` = 3)
    AND 
    (`archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate` >= CURDATE()))
GROUP BY
`archived_items`.`ArcPartNumber`
`archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate`,
ORDER BY
`archived_items`.`ArcPartNumber`,
`archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are only grouping by two of the columns you should be. Not sure if this a typo or the cause of the problem. Try this instead

```
SELECT
    `archived_items`.`ArcPartNumber` AS `PartNum`,
    `archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate` AS `DeliveryDate`,
    `archived_items`.`ArcTransactionNumber` AS `TransactionNumber`,
    sum(`archived_items`.`ArcOrdered`) AS `Ordered`,
    sum(`archived_items`.`ArcShipped`) AS `Shipped`,
    sum(`archived_items`.`ArcBackOrdered`) AS `BackOrdered`
FROM
    ( `archived_items`
        LEFT JOIN `archived_header` ON (
            (`archived_header`.`AhTransactionNumber` = `archived_items`.`ArcTransactionNumber`
        )))
WHERE
((`archived_items`.`ArcTransactionType` = 3)
    AND 
    (`archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate` >= CURDATE()))
GROUP BY
`archived_items`.`ArcPartNumber`
`archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate`,
`archived_items`.`ArcTransactionNumber`
ORDER BY
`archived_items`.`ArcPartNumber`,
`archived_header`.`AhDeliveryDate`
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. Same results. This is really weird.

Comment: It's not the view. Something else is wrong. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try this . you use much those `()` in no needed places

```
 SELECT
       ar.`ArcPartNumber` AS `PartNum`,
       ah.`AhDeliveryDate` AS `DeliveryDate`,
       ar.`ArcTransactionNumber` AS `TransactionNumber`,
       sum(ar.`ArcOrdered`) AS `Ordered`,
       sum(ar.`ArcShipped`) AS `Shipped`,
       sum(ar.`ArcBackOrdered`) AS `BackOrdered`
 FROM   `archived_items` ar
 LEFT JOIN `archived_header` ah 
 ON    ah.`AhTransactionNumber` = ar.`ArcTransactionNumber`
 WHERE
       ar.`ArcTransactionType` = 3
 AND 
      ah.`AhDeliveryDate` >= CURDATE()   
 GROUP BY
       `PartNum`,
       `DeliveryDate`
 ORDER BY
       `PartNum`,
       `DeliveryDate`
```

// dont use `CURDATE` beecause its already a function of curent date. i replaced it by your `ah.AhDeliveryDate` so  be sure that they are same format

[**look demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/110e8/1) it works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That extra CURDATE was a typo on my part. So your view is my view and thus I still get a partial data set. Note that all those parenthesis are generated by Navicat which I'm using.

Comment: edited my code , it was some wrong comma , try now the code above and see the demo

Comment: Thanks for your demo. As I said above, it's something else. I appreciate all the help.